# Perl - Converting 4 .txt files to 2 hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to create two hashes, from 4 text files, each with matching # of lines, containing addresses to be matched with the city.

I'm hoping this will be a fairly easy one, everything is working except I want to store the values in the hashes without the line break, but every other option I've tried when creating the merged text files later reads the address and city into the array as one entry, not two separate.

Also, is there a simple way to remove the "NewCombo" and "OldCombo" text files by just putting the values directly into an array? same thing with the array to hash later, I haven't been able to get anything but this working, yet I feel like my code is clumsy and excessive as-is. Although, I'm happy my only real issue is getting rid of the line break before I can continue with this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $nafile = 'na.txt';
my $ncfile = 'nc.txt';
my $oafile = 'oa.txt';
my $ocfile = 'oc.txt';


open my $nafh, $nafile or die "Can't open New Address file!";
open my $ncfh, $ncfile or die "Can't open New City file!";
open my $oafh, $oafile or die "Can't open Old Address file!";
open my $ocfh, $ocfile or die "Can't open Old City file!";

open my $fh, '>', "NewCombo.txt" or die "Cannot open NewCombo.txt!";
while ( my $a = <$nafh>, my $b = <$ncfh> ) { 
    chomp( $a, $b );
    printf $fh qq|%s\n%s\n|, $a, $b; 
}
close $fh;

open my $fh2, '>', "OldCombo.txt" or die "Cannot open OldCombo.txt!";
while ( my $c = <$oafh>, my $d = <$ocfh> ) { 
    chomp( $c, $d );
    printf $fh2 qq|%s\n%s\n|, $c, $d; 
}
close $fh2;

my $OldFile = "OldCombo.txt";
open (FH, "< $OldFile") or die "Can't open OldFile for read!";
my @OldCombo;
while (<FH>) {
    push (@OldCombo, $_);
}
close FH or die "Cannot close OldFile!";

my $NewFile = "NewCombo.txt";
open (FH, "< $NewFile") or die "Can't open $NewFile for read: $!";
my @NewCombo;
while (<FH>) {
    push (@NewCombo, $_);
}
close FH or die "Cannot close NewFile!";

my %NewCombo = @NewCombo;
my %OldCombo = @OldCombo;

print %NewCombo;
print %OldCombo;
```

I think I'm decent all around when it comes to programming, and have an understanding of the logic behind MOST code. I'm still very new to Perl though, any help is appreciated

Added details - I've tried delimiting the values with commas, tabs, and spaces, and every combination of them between/after each "set" of values

Comment: No point in first `chomp`ing values, then printing them back with a newline. Just print them without chomping: `print $fh $a, $b`

Comment: Try printing the hashes with `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper \%NewCombo, \%OldCombo;` This should show you what the data structures look like, and any misplaced line endings.

Comment: @TLP - Thanks for the input, with the chomp I'm not sure why, but I can't get an output file of address-city, address-city, address-city, except doing that, although it seems excessive... My out put without it is more like address address address city city city city city address address city etc, obviously I have no clue why :/. As for the Data::Dumper, going to try that now! thanks again

Comment: Data::Dumper is great, never used it before, definitely a tool I'll remember.

Comment: Well, did you find anything strange? You could paste a sample of the Data::Dumper output into the question to help us figure out whats wrong.

Comment: And no, it is logically impossible that removing `chomp` would change the order from `address-city-address-city` to `address-address-city-city`.

Comment: I'm just going off of what I got in the output, and that was the only difference. I can't say it doesn't confuse me beyond reason... though removing strictly the "chomp($a, $b); and the "\n"'s doesn't actually mix up the order, but it seems to be skipping some addresses and cities, giving me the address-address-city-city issue. Should have worded that differently. removing just the chomp gives me no cities, just addresses. I'll have to create some fictional sample data to get an output I can post here. will add asap

Comment: @TLP - *"...it is logically impossible..."*  It's *programmatically impossible*, but logically possible--especially with the chaotic interventions of a Cartesian evil demon.  A simple, confirmatory test is to imagine the order changing after `chomp`.  If it were impossible, I couldn't imagine it--like a square circle or a light being simultaneously on and off at the same instant, both of which being logically impossible.  After all, even Socrates couldn't both sit and stand at the same time...

Comment: @Kenosis I reserve the right to not patch my statements to cover the effects of Cartesian evil demons.

Comment: @TCooper I can't help you beyond this point without resorting to guessing. You have to provide information to move this forward.

Comment: @TLP - Thanks--I needed that good laugh...  Or did I???! ;)

Comment: @Kenosis If you laugh and no one is there to hear it, did you enjoy it?

Comment: @TLP - I wish I could award you points for your responses.  And how did you know that I am in a forest?

Comment: @TLP - I really appreciate it, but I got the output I need just using the simple regex below. Strictly because of time I'm going to stick with this code, however slow it may be. Shouldn't be running with any text files over 20k lines, so can't take too long... I hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your `$/` is differ from line endings in your files. You can apply regexp `s/[\r\n]//g` for any line you read.

Comment: thanks! that is working to remove from the value, but not from the key, trying to tweak it some now.

Comment: If by key you mean `@oldCombo` and `@newCombo` in your code sample you do not `chomp` values which push in

Comment: not what I was going for, but simple, and works for what I need. Due to time I'm taking this solution, hopefully I can come back and make it pretty another day